# Change /search to /somethingelse

Tags: url-rewriting, search

How do I change the search url?
I already have something like: /search/keyword
But I want to change /search to something else.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: What has been your research so far? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. More info about how to ask a good question can be found on the [ask] page.

Comment: yes, I did search in google and wordpress stackexchange but haven't found a solution that did work ok, and some of the solutions were a bit old. So I put here the question to see if there are any better and updated solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution I'm now using is to create a rewrite rule in .htaccess (on the root of wp project) like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^\&]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pesquisar/%1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

I don't know if it's the best solution but seems to be working ok!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your functions.php in your theme folder:

```
function change_search_url_rewrite() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/somethingelse/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_search_url_rewrite' );
```

Comment: Wouldn't `WP_Rewrite` do that as well without an extra redirect?

Comment: Probably. This is just one possible solution; it might not be the best. Unfortunately I am not very familiar with WP_Rewrite and I am also struggling with it.